# Why is touchCancelled getting called in CCResponder?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a grid that I'm setting up like this:

```
CCLayoutBox *_grid; = [CCLayoutBox new];

_grid.direction = CCLayoutBoxDirectionVertical;
_grid.spacing = -2.0f;
_grid.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"game-play-elements/1-square-yellow-70x70-2px.png"];

for (int i = 0; i < GRID_ROWS; i++) {
    CCLayoutBox *row = [CCLayoutBox new];

    row.direction = CCLayoutBoxDirectionHorizontal;
    row.spacing = -1.0f;

    for(int j = 0; j < GRID_COLUMNS; j++) {
        CCSprite *cell = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:frame];
        [row addChild:cell];
    }

    [_grid addChild:row];
}
```

During the game I place a sprite inside the grid by adding a sprite as a child of the cell sprite. In the main gameplay implementation I then look to see if the player has touched a node intending to move it to a different cell. However whenever I move beyond the borders of the cell a touchCancelled fires which prevents the player from moving it to a different cell.

Any idea why this might be happening? Is there some property I need to set to get this to work as intended?

Troubleshooting Steps:

1. I set a breakpoint in my gameplay implementation of `-(void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and noticed that the caller of this method `CCResponderManager` is using my gameplay node as the target and that it is claiming user interaction via `node.claimsUserInteraction`.

Comment: There seems to be a clue to this type of behavior here but I didn't fully understand birkemose's answer. http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/touch-cancels-on-movement-what-am-i-doing-wrong/14366/3